# AS3: Include pictures in a Quiz Game which loads questions in random

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone help me on how to include pictures in a quiz game in which the questions loads in random? I already have a game in which the questions and answers are being added in the array. If the user is finish typing his answer in the text field, he will then click a button and the game will display if the answer is correct or not. If all the questions are being loaded, the game will automatically ends. It works perfectly but I want to show some pictures together with the questions. Like for example, there’s a question:”What bird is this?” and there’s a picture of a bird together with the question. How am I going to implement this? Also, not just pictures but can I also include an swf or a movieclip? I’m thinking that an animation is much cooler than pictures. But if not, pictures is alright. Here’s the code..I really appreciate any help.

```
var quizModel:Array = [{q:"1+1 = ?", a:"2"}, {q:"5+5 = ?", a:"10"}, {q:"2+2 = ?", a:"4"}, {q:"6+6 = ?", a:"12"},{q:"8-7 = ?",a:"1"}];

var user_ans:Array = new Array();
var newQuizModel:Array = shuffleArray(quizModel);

function shuffleArray(arr:Array):Array
{
    var l:Number = arr.length - 1;

    for (var it:uint = 0; it<l; it++)
    {
    var r:int = Math.round(Math.random() * l);
    var tmp:Object = arr[it];
    arr[it] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = tmp;
    }
return arr;
}

var index:int = 0;
questions_txt.text = newQuizModel[index]["q"];

submit.label = "Submit";  //This is a button I made from the” windows->component” that has a label “Submit”. If clicked, it will check if the answer is correct or not 

submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,yow);

function yow (event:MouseEvent):void{  //Runs if the Submit button is clicked

    if (userAnswer.text == newQuizModel[index]["a"]) 
    {
        answers_txt.text = "Your answer is correct!";
    }
    else
    {
        answers_txt.text = "Your answer is wrong";
    }

    index++;

if(index == quizModel.length){  //Runs if all of the questions in the array loads
    Over.text = "It's Over!";
    index--;
    submit.visible=false;
    questions_txt.visible=false;
    userAnswer.visible=false;
}
    showQuiz(index);

}

function showQuiz(idx:int):void
{
    questions_txt.text = "Question: " + newQuizModel[idx]["q"];
}

showQuiz(index);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you working in Flash? If in Flash you could put your pictures or movie clips in the fla's library and then instantiate them as you display each question.

For example, give them a Export for Actionscript Class name in their properties dialog. Then add the class name to each of your question's data like this:

```
{q:"1+1 = ?", a:"2", className: "two_birds"}
```

Next, instantiate the symbol from the library and add to your display list like this:

```
var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(newQuizModel[idx]["className"]) as Class;
var displayObj:Object = new classRef();
addChild(displayObj);
displayObj.x=20;
displayObj.y=20;
```

Or something like that. I'll leave you to work out the details.

Comment: thanks for the reply..yes..I'm working in flash..I'll try it right away..thank you very much..I'll be in touch if I have errors though..